# Realtime local reflections of particle system

Tags: directx11, reflection-rendering, cryengine

I'm finding my way around CryEngine 3 (through Steam) and want to create a simple effect where a fire on shore is reflected in a body of water.

For testing purposes, I've made the water dead calm...

[image: Problem]

(Note Dx11 on 2nd line of debug info)

As you can see, the terrain is reflected properly, but the flame particles aren't reflected. It's my understanding that this [should be possible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHJMJ_GcBLc&t=1m38s).

NB: I've created an appropriate cubemap for the water environment, although I don't believe it comes into play here.

I've seen a number of posts saying Glossiness > 50 (or 50%) and a light specular color are required. I've got 100% and white...

[image: Material Editor]

And for completeness, the water volume properties...

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I need to enable to get this working? Thanks.